# Doctrine 2 - Using a PersistentCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently in the process of writing tests for some legacy code.  One of the entities I'm working on contains an `ArrayCollection` of other entities in a One-to-Many relationship.  When I load the data in my fixtures, I can see that the entities on the One side of the relationship correctly contain the entities on the Many side of the relationship using PhpStorm's debugger.

Apparently, an `ArrayCollection` becomes a `PersistentCollection` when it's persisted to the database.

The method I'm currently testing is attempting to iterate through this newly formed `PersistentCollection` with a `foreach`, but, well, nothing is happening.  The collection, according to the debugger, contains relationship metadata, but doesn't retrieve the values I entered into the original `ArrayCollection`.

Example pseudo-code (due to a NDA):

```
class Entity1 
{
    private $items;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addItem(Entity2 $item) {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return $this->items;
    }
}

class Entity2 {}

$child1 = new Entity2();
$child2 = new Entity2();
$child3 = new Entity2();

$ent = new Entity1();

$ent->addItem($child1);
$ent->addItem($child2);
$ent->addItem($child3);

// persist them all with the entity manager

// end data fixtures

// inside a different file, in the method I'm trying to test:

$items = $ent->getItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // nothing happens as $items contains metadata/relationship data, but doesn't (lazy) load
    // the Entity2 instances
}
```

And here's an actual screenshot of what's in the `PersistentCollection`:

[image]

Note how the `coll` collection, which I assume is what should be filled with my `Entity2` instances, is empty.

So, I'm at a bit of a loss.  I need to be able to access the Entity2 instances, but it's not happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: is `$child3 = new Entity3();` a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: This is typical when your relationship does not have a properly configured cascade parameter. How are you declaring the OneToMany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Attempting to relate entities by adding `Entity2` instances to `Entity1`'s `ArrayCollection` wasn't working.  None of the `Entity2` instances had an id of an `Entity1` as a foreign key.  Doing it the opposite way - manually setting the `Entity1` for every `Entity2` - worked, and I can now iterate through the collection.

I'm not sure if that behavior - not being able to create/enforce/whatever a relation through an `ArrayCollection` is defined behavior or a bug, but I figure I should post my solution here in any event.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cascade parameter to you OneToMany configuration. If using annotations:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity2", mappedBy="entity1", cascade={"persist"})
*/
```

Adjust the mappedBy parameter to your actual implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't remedy the situation.  My cascade was originally set to `all`, which I believe contains `persist`, but even after changing it *to* `persist` the problem remains.  I can see the metadata, but that's it.  I'm going to add a screenshot to my original question so you and others can see what I mean